# 12-month Calendar in C

Tags: c

I'm making a 12-month calendar in C. A program that displays twelve-month calendar for a particular year. The program prompts the user for the year to be printed, and figures out (a) whether the year is a leap-year and (b) what day of the week the chosen year starts on.

Instructions:

•   main() prompts the user for input, calls a function of your own design to determine the starting day of the input year. It then invokes the function printCalendar() to actually print the twelve month calendar.

•   printCalendar() takes two arguments, the year number and the starting day. It then loops through the year and calls the function printMonth() twelve times, once for each month.

•   printMonth() takes three arguments, the year number, the month number and the starting day of that particular month, and it returns the number of the day on which the next month starts. Print month has to first call a function printMonthName() and then print out the days of the month in calendar format.

•   printMonthName() takes the year number and the month number as arguments, prints out the line identifying the month, and returns the number of days in that month, taking into account leap year.

I followed those instructions and got this far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int daysInMonth;
int getDayCode(int year);
void printCalendar(int year, int dayCode);
int getYear(void);

int getYear(void){
  int year;
  printf("Please enter a year: ");
  scanf("%i", &year);
  printf("\n");
  return year;
}

int getDayCode(int year){
  int dayCode;
  int x1, x2, x3;
          x1 = (year - 1.)/ 4.0;
          x2 = (year - 1.)/ 100.;
          x3 = (year - 1.)/ 400.;
  dayCode = (year + x1 - x2 + x3) %7;
  return dayCode;
}

main(){
  int year, dayCode;
  year = getYear();
  dayCode = getDayCode(year);
  printCalendar(year, dayCode);

}

void printCalendar(int year, int dayCode){
   int month;
   printf("        %d Monthly Calendar\n", year);
   printf(" \n");
   printf(" \n");
   for (month = 1; month <= 12; month++){
     printMonth(year, month, dayCode);
   }
}

int printMonthName(int year, int month){
  switch (month){
  case 1:
       printf("\n\nJanuary %i", year);
       daysInMonth = 31;
       return daysInMonth;
       break;
  case 2:
       printf("\n\nFebruary %i", year);
       if (year%4 == 0 && year%100 != 0 || year%400 == 0){
         //printf("This is a leap year.\n");
         daysInMonth = 29;
         return daysInMonth;
       }
      else{
        //printf("This is not a leap year.\n");
        daysInMonth = 28;
        return daysInMonth;
      }
      break;
 case 3:
      printf("\n\nMarch %i", year);
      daysInMonth = 31;
      return daysInMonth;
      break;
 case 4:
      printf("\n\nApril %i", year);
      daysInMonth = 30;
      return daysInMonth;
      break;
 case 5:
      printf("\n\nMay %i", year);
      daysInMonth = 31;
      return daysInMonth;
      break;
 case 6:
      printf("\n\nJune %i", year);
      daysInMonth = 30;
      return daysInMonth;
      break;
 case 7:
      printf("\n\nJuly %i", year);
      daysInMonth = 31;
      return daysInMonth;
      break;
 case 8:
      printf("\n\nAugust %i", year);
      daysInMonth = 31;
      return daysInMonth;
      break;
 case 9:
      printf("\n\nSeptember %i", year);
      daysInMonth = 30;
      return daysInMonth;
      break;
 case 10:
      printf("\n\nOctober %i", year);
      daysInMonth = 31;
      return daysInMonth;
      break;
 case 11:
      printf("\n\nNovember %i", year);
      daysInMonth = 30;
      return daysInMonth;
      break;
 case 12:
      printf("\n\nDecember %i", year);
      daysInMonth = 31;
      return daysInMonth;
      break;
 default:
      printf("Invalid input! Please try again!\n");
      break;
    }
}

int printMonth(int year, int month, int dayCode){
 int day;
 printMonthName(year, month);
 printf("\n\nSun  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri  Sat\n" );
 /* advance printer to correct position for first date */
 for (day = 1; day <= 1 + dayCode * 5; day++)
 printf(" ");
 /* print the dates for one month */
 for (day = 1; day <= daysInMonth; day++){
   printf("%2d", day);
   if ((day + dayCode) % 7 > 0) /* before Sat? */
     /* move to next day in same week */
     printf("   ");
   else  /* skip to next line to start with Sun */
     printf("\n ");
   }
   /* set day_code for next month to begin */
   dayCode = (dayCode + daysInMonth % 7);
   return dayCode;
}
```

I put 2013 as input year, and my code starts January 1st on Tuesday, which is correct. But it is also starting on Tuesday for all 12 months, here is the problem:
[Calendar Output 2013](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sm8wT.png)

Please help. I've been trying to get this to work for a long time now.

Comment: I'm using Atom, it doesn't debug? i believe. I'll check again.

Comment: `printMonth` returns `dayCode` but you never use it in `printCalendar`.

Comment: There are some very strange `double` values in there such as `x1 = (year - 1.)/ 4.0;`

Comment: @HeartKiller If your question doesn't deal with a _specific_ problem, it is off-topic here. Also, failure to debug and report the results thereof will get you downvotes.

Comment: Do not fundamentally change the question, especially once answers arrive.  Question rolled back.  If needed, learn from this post, fix as much as you can, finish this post  and later post a new question (adding a link back to this one.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if you return `dayCode` in your `printMonth` function. However, you never do anything with that value in your `printCalendar` function. This is easily fixed by changing your for loop in `printCalendar`.

```
for (month = 1; month <= 12; month++){
    dayCode = printMonth(year, month, dayCode);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I changed the code, but now something is wrong with the formatting. I edited the post and attached a new picture.

Comment: Oh, that is because when you are calculating the new day code in `printMonth`, the `%` has a higher precedence compared to the `+` sign.

So `dayCode = (dayCode + daysInMonth % 7);` is the same as `dayCode = dayCode + (daysInMonth % 7);`

Comment: @HeartKiller Adding text rather than pictures of text is good.  Picture of text attract down-votes.

Comment: It was all because of a misplaced parenthesis. Thanks a lot @mageliz. Everything works now.